# GASでセルの文章に変数をあてはめたい

Tags: google-apps-script

**やりたいこと**
GASを使用してGSSのセルからdiscordにメッセージを送りたいと思っております。
たくさんのdiscordのチャンネルに文章を送りたいと考えているため、
同じ形のコードを作り、違うところだけ変数にしてデータを送りたいと考えています。
しかし、おくりたい文章のひな形が変わる恐れがあり、もし変わるとなるとコードを一つ一つ変える必要性があります。

例えば以下の様な形になるのですが、このmessageの文章が変わる可能性があるということです。

```
var agecoord = sheet.getRange(2,6); 
var age = agecoord.getValue();
 
var message = "私は" + age + "になります。";
```

ですので、スプレットシートにこの文章を書き込み、取り出して出力したいのですが、
この場合、ageの変数扱いされないので困っています。

取り出したい文章を `"私は" + age + "になります。"` にした場合、
どのようにすれば変数ageをあてはめることができるでしょうか？

**実際書いてみたコード**

```
function submit(){
  discord(get_value())
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('スプレットシートURL',0);
  //配信時間
  var a = sheet.getRange(2,6); 
  var atime = a.getValue();
  //format
  var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(99, 3);
  var format = formatcoord.getValue();
  
  return format;
};

function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};

function discord(message) {
    const url        = 'discord webhookURL';
    const token      = 'discord token';
    const channel    = '#channel';
    const text       = message;
    const username   = '  discord1';
    const parse      = 'full';
    const method     = 'post';

    const payload = {
        'token'      : token,
        'channel'    : channel,
        "content"    : text,
        'username'   : username,
        'parse'      : parse,
    };

    const params = {
        'method' : method,
        'payload' : payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true

    };

   response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ちょっと質問が理解しにくいのですが、こういうことでしょうか。

```
const age = "30"; // 実際にはシートから値を取得
const format = '"私は" + age + "になります"'; // 実際にはシートから値を取得

const message = eval(format);
console.log(message); // 私は30になります
```

ただ、`eval()`は危険なので使うべきでない。

[eval() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

そこで`Function()`を使うなら

```
const message = Function('const age = ' + age + '; return ' + format + ';')();
```

でしょうか。

Comment: 無事に実行できました！